# Accessing a servlet's mapping from Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, url-mapping

The following code accesses a servlet's name: `servletConfig.getServletName()`.
Can I access a servlet's URL pattern in a similar way?

An excerpt from web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>This is the servlet's name</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/this-is-its-url-pattern/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is available in the Servlet API. Either parse the `web.xml` yourself, or duplicate it as an `<init-param>` of the servlet wherein you'd like to access it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Servlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>url-pattern</param-name>
        <param-value>/servlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way it's available by `servletConfig.getInitParameter("url-pattern")`.

Answer (score 5):

In Servlet 3.0 (or Java EE 6) spec exist something:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html

You can get a ServletRegistration using [ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration%28java.lang.String%29).